# How to add a custom image to a textfield in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, textfield, horizontalfieldmanager

Trying to add a background image to a textfield but when a user types over and goes into a horizontal scroll the image seems to be replicated over causing it to look like the following:
[image]

Basically i want the 1st textfield to look like the 2nd after the user has inputed a large value. I have a class that extends horizontalfieldManager and in my paint function is the following:

```
protected void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.clear();
    if (mLabelMode)
    {
        g.setColor(mLabelColor);
    }
    else
    {
        g.setColor(mColor);
    }

    int x = this.getHorizontalScroll();

    g.drawImage(x, 0, mBackground.getWidth(), mBackground.getHeight(), mBackground, 0, 0, 0);

    super.paint(g);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this:

[Using image for a TextEditField in Blackberry](http://swati-blackberry.blogspot.in/2011/01/using-image-for-texteditfield-in.html)